# C++ Is it possible that the base class has a function with a parameter of the derived class

Tags: c++, include, instance, radix, derived

I want to do essentially the following:

```
class Base{
     void dosomestuff(Derived instanceOfDerived)
     {
         //Something
     }
};

class Derived : public Base{
     //Something
};
```

The Base needs a include of Derived, but to declare Derived it needs the declaration of Base first. Forward declaration does not work, because I do not want to use pointers.

Now my question: How do I accomplish that without pointers? Is that even possible? Or is the only possibility to make instanceOfDerived a pointer?

Comment: Im sorry. You are completely right. I changed the example, the question is the same.

Comment: If you want to refer to something that hasn't been defined yet, you need some kind of indirection like a pointer or reference. (Note that you can't *use* the derived class inside the definition of the base class, you can only refer to it by name; you'll need to move the function definition.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original version of the question asks about having `Base` hold `Derived` as a data member. That's obviously impossible. It's the same infinite recursion problem (a `Derived` contains a `Base` subobject, so a `Base` would recursively contain itself, and it will be turtles all the way down.)

The revised question asks about having a member function of `Base` taking a by-value argument of type `Derived`. That's perfectly possible. You need a forward declaration of `Derived`, and to defer the definition of the member function until after the actual definition of `Derived`:

```
class Derived;
class Base{
     void dosomestuff(Derived instanceOfDerived); // declaration only
};

class Derived : public Base{
     //Something
};

// out-of-class definition, so making it explicitly inline
// to match the in-class definition semantics
inline void Base::dosomestuff(Derived instanceOfDerived) {
     //Something
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ccee8ec57b5df18).

Comment: full of surprises... nice!

Answer (score 3):

You better do something like:

```
class Derived;
class Base{
     void dosomestuff(Derived& instanceOfDerived)
     {
         //Something
     }
};

class Derived : public Base{
     //Something
};
```

I would even move the body of method `dosomestuff` to the source cpp code where you can include derived.h as well as base.h

base.h could look like:

```
#ifndef BASE_H_
#define BASE_H_

class Derived;
class Base{
     void dosomestuff(const Derived& instanceOfDerived);
};

#endif
```

derived.h:

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H_
#define DERIVED_H_

#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base{
     //Something
};

#endif
```

base.cpp:

```
#include "base.h"
#include "derived.h"

void Base::dosomestuff(const Derived &instanceOfDerived) {
    //Something
}
```

Comment: What if they don't want to take a reference?

Comment: @JosephMansfield the interface of Derived cannot be accessable from Base in a simple way...

Comment: So I need to use a either a pointer or a reference? There is no other way?

Comment: Alas no, there is not.

Comment: @MoritzG I'm afraid so, but on the other hand it's not much of a limitation with references...

Comment: @MoritzG - You always try to reduce creating temporary objects, if you don't pass by `*` or `&`. If this code is going in production, don't try that or else if using for learning use it, debug and see how many copy constructor calls are made.

Comment: @WojciechFrohmberg, since the original function took its parameter by value, your fix should take a const-reference. Also `_BASE_` and `_DERIVED_` are [reserved names](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/981959), so this answer has undefined behaviour. Bad bad bad.

Comment: Thank you. Im just learning C++ so I just wanted to know if this would be possible. It is a good advice to use more pointers and references.
Im not working on production. Im just practicing C++. Im coming from C# and Java. So I have a lot to learn :)

In my projects I use the .h files. I just did not use it in the example to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

That means your inheritance model is not make sense if you really want to do that. Remember "Make sure public inheritance models 'is a.' "http://debian.fmi.uni-sofia.bg/~mrpaff/Effective%20C++/EC/EI35_FR.HTM
If you make them have inheritance relationship, that means Derived is a Base, instead of "Derived is part of Base".
You can create 2 classes to do that instead of making them have inheritance relationship.